Run a bash script in Linux on a specific queue
I have a shell script on Linux to extract NetCDF data for each grid into a .txt file.
This is the annual averaged NetCDF data that I used in this conversion (originally was daily data), the size was 85.1 MB
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nud5b3KvjtE8H4Ol73zdnNSb9eeItaY7/view?usp=sharing
The script runs correctly without any errors. All
of the mentioned script has been checked using https://www.shellcheck.net/ and there is no error.
This is my script named extract_global.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Define input file, log file, and output directory
input_file="canesm5_r1i1p1f1_w5e5_ssp126_tas_global_daily_2015_2100_05gc.nc"
log_file="log.txt"
output_dir="/path/output/"  # Replace with the desired output directory

export PATH=/home/appl/cdo-1.9.8/bin/cdo:$PATH

# Remove existing log file if it exists
rm -f $log_file

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
#mkdir -p $output_dir

# Function to extract data for a specific latitude
extract_latitude() {
    lat=$1
    lon_index=1
    max_jobs=20
    job_count=0
    pids=()

    # Loop through longitudes from -180 to 180 in 0.5 degree increments
    for lon in $(seq -180 0.5 179.5); do
        # Define the output file name based on the current latitude and longitude index
        output_file="${output_dir}${lat}_${lon_index}.txt"
        
        # Extract data for the grid point at the current latitude and longitude, save only values, and remove the header
        (/home/appl/cdo-1.9.8/bin/cdo -outputtab,value -remapnn,lon="${lon}"_lat="${lat}" $input_file | sed '1d' > "$output_file") &>> $log_file &
        
        # Store the PID of the background job
        pids+=($!)

        # Increment the longitude index and job count
        lon_index=$((lon_index + 1))
        job_count=$((job_count + 1))

        # Check if the max number of jobs has been reached
        if [ $job_count -ge $max_jobs ]; then
            # Wait for all the jobs to finish
            for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
                wait "$pid"
            done
            pids=()  # Reset the PID array
            job_count=0  # Reset job count
        fi
    done

    # Wait for any remaining background processes to finish
    for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
        wait "$pid"
    done
}

# Loop through latitudes from 90N to -90S in 0.5 degree increments
for lat in $(seq 90 -0.5 -90); do
    echo "Extracting data for latitude $lat"
    extract_latitude "$lat"
done

echo "Data extraction completed. Check $log_file for details."

If I run ./extract_global.sh directly, the program runs correctly: extract every 20 grid points, wait until the current job is finished then continue the next loop, and produce the correct data extraction inside each produced .txt file.
By default, all jobs on our Linux server run on the main CPU. I want to change the CPU used for this job by changing to a different queue.
The main CPU is used by several members, so running heavy jobs can slow down the server. Therefore, in the code above, I set the maximum number of jobs to 20 and used a loop. However, this makes the process very long and inefficient.
I tried to solve this matter, by creating a go.bat file to set up the queue and other configurations. The contents of the go.bat file are as follows:
#!/bin/sh
#$ -S /bin/sh
#$ -q ib.q@node02   # Specify the queue
#$ -N SSP_kzm      # Define job name
#$ -j y             # Standard output and error message will be written in the same file
#$ -e /path/log.txt  # Specify the error file
#$ -M mail@gmail.com
#$ -m be            # Send email at the beginning and end of the job


# Load necessary modules
# module load cdo

# Or if cdo is in a custom directory, add it to the PATH
export PATH=/home/appl/cdo-1.9.8/bin/cdo:$PATH

cd /path/
./extract_global.sh >& log.txt


Finally, I ran the job with the settings in the run.sh file, as shown below:
#!/bin/bash

# Submit the conversion program and wait for it to complete
qsub go.bat
echo "Waiting for conversion computation"
date

# Wait for the job to finish
while qstat | grep -q kzm; do
  sleep 5
done

date
echo "Job completed"


I ran by using
nohup ./run.sh >& log.txt & 
Then, I checked by qstat -f and I got this information:
queuename  qtype resv/used/tot. np_load  arch          states
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ib.q@node02 BIP   0/1/20         0.05   lx-amd64 
19847 0.50500 SSP_kzm  kzm   r     10/10/2024 09:28:04     1        
----------------------------------------------------------------------


Results:

The program ignores the "wait" command inside 'extract_global.sh' script, and produces the output .txt file very quickly.
The program successfully generated all of the .txt files according to the grid area of the NetCDF file, but the .txt files were empty. In addition, the script produced numerous files named "cores.number" are around 4MB each file with unreadable characters if we open it directly using the text editor.
No errors detected in log.txt, but there is no value stored in the .txt output.
I'm not sure if the method I'm using is correct. I've looked for information and tried similar solutions, but I haven't been able to fix it yet.

The main point is that I want to run the ./extract_global.sh script on a queue named ib.q@node02 and I want to allocate the whole available CPU on that node (20 CPUs) to fasten the conversion process.
Should I use MPI parallel computation to be able to use the whole CPU on that node?
If someone is able to help me, I would be very grateful.
Thank you.

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

I don't have access to sample input files, and I couldn't spend the time even if I did. I recommend you read  the sections Before asking about problematic code, AND How to turn a bad script into a good question from the samebash tag as mentioned above (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash). You should try to boil your problem down to code that readers can copy/paste into their environment and see the same problem. Not voting to close as you are an early poster, and you did post a very nice clean entry. Good luck!

@EdMorton, I apologize for my mistake, i didn't check my script previously because I just know about this and my conversion script worked well (there is no error). However, now I have checked all of my scripts using https://www.shellcheck.net/. Thank you for the information

@shellter now i have updated my information, I uploaded the simplified data and all of the scripts have been checked using https://www.shellcheck.net/, and there is no significant change because individually the conversion script (extract_global.sh) was worked. Thank you very much for your support and kindness. Have a good day! :)

The immediate solution to your current error message is to add a line near the top of your extract_...sh script like export PATH="/full/path/to:$PATH" where the /full/path/to directory contains the cdo cmd. Not elegant, but this should get you thinking about the differences between your terminal environment and the environment where the command is failing. I mentioned "How to turn a bad script ..." because your problem, (as described now) is on one line of code. A much smaller script could have still demonstrrated this problem. Well. going to bed. Good luck!

@Kazuma please [edit] your question to replace the faulty scripts with the shellcheck-clean versions so we can see the actual script you are now asking for help to debug rather than the pre-shellcheck version to make it easier for us to help you.

@EdMorton I'm not sure about the suitability of the topic I'm asking about with the title you suggested. But I have adjusted it, because I am new here and I respect you as a senior who has more experience in this matter. Thank you for the suggestion.

@shellter Thank you very much for the suggestion, I have added PATH cdo to the 'extract_global.sh' shell script. The previous problem that cdo is not detected, we can solve it by calling cdo with full path in the extraction command '/home/appl/cdo-1.9.8/bin/cdo -outputtab..' At this time, the program may be almost complete, but I am still having problems with how to run the program using the entire CPU on the node to speed up the conversion process. If you can help me check in your spare time, I would be very grateful.

``xargsorrgnu-parallel(offten just namedparallelmay help, but you loop with backgrounding of individual "threads" seems OK. You need to capture the PID of each background process as you launch them withjobPID=$!. Then you could use taskset -cp 0 1234 would bind the process with PID 1234 to CPU core 0. you'd manage the core number with a incrementing variable. I used to use pbind under SunOS for "hardwiring" a process to a core, but assuming you have a Linux OS, it is more likely that you have taskset available. I never used it so won't be able to help further.

man taskset . Good luck!

I didn't suggest you change the title to "Replace the faulty scripts with the shellcheck-clean version" - I suggested that you [edit] your question to do that, i.e. remove the scripts currently present in the question and show the ones you fixed after running shellcheck instead so we're not looking at code that contains errors that shellcheck can detect. I put the title back as it was.
